# Combine seekbar and progressbar to create media player with trim support

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

We'd like to create a player/trimmer...

[image]

Inside the blue box is the touch area for progress, in the yellow box are the trimmers which are used to set start and end point.

We're using a custom view like "range-seek-bar" for this purpose. The handlers image are clipping off the seek-bar view and into another view (see the image below). 
What we're trying to achieve is clicking only on those handler's circle (not the entire image) to move the handler, but since those are bitmaps and the click is being made outside the seek bar view, we cannot get the OnClick call. Be able to listen when the user clicks inside those red square.

[image]

Many thanks for your help and replies.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check this library also: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

The "range-seek-bar" that I linked doesn't allow touches outside the thumbs. You can then modify the drawables and its onDraw() to visually customize it (make transparent for example). Modify it to allow it to be thumbless, to be used as the top progressbar. So you'll have two of those: one thumbless as the top progressbar, one with thumbs but with transparent lines as the bottom seekbar.

```
boolean isNotLineless; // Set this in constructor or a setter
boolean isNotThumbless; // Set this in constructor or a setter

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (isNotLineless) {
        // draw seek bar background line
        final RectF rect = new RectF(padding, 0.5f * (getHeight() - lineHeight), getWidth() - padding, 0.5f * (getHeight() + lineHeight));
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

        // draw seek bar active range line
        rect.left = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue);
        rect.right = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue);

        // orange color
        paint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    if (isNotThumbless) {
        // draw minimum thumb
        drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue), Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);

        // draw maximum thumb 
        drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue), Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);
    }
}
```

**For the thumbless version**, also handle its touch events.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isEnabled() || !isNotThumbless)
        return false;
```

Comment: He is asking how to expand touch view to be able to use those Handlers from outside the SeekBar View.

Comment: We're using a custom view like "range-seek-bar" for this purpose. The handlers image are clipping of the seek-bar view and into another view (See the image below). What we're trying to achieve is clicking only on those Handler's circle (not the entire image) move the handler, but since those are bitmap and the click is being made outside the seek bar view, we cannot get the OnClick call.  

http://imgur.com/iipiO2C.png  
Be able to listen when the user clicks inside those red square.

Comment: @AgustinAlvarez You want the user to be UNABLE to touch both the transparent parts of the thumb, and the progress bar itself? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly just the area within the red square

Comment: Added modifications to the answer.